# Evaluate a Heaviside step function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

So I have this question that I don't know how to do.

> The Heaviside step function H(x) (also called unit step function) is a discontinuous 
>        function whose value is 0 for negative x and 1 for positive x. That is, it can be defined as:

```
        H(x) = {0 if x<0}
               {1 if x>0}

Evaluate ∫ 2 to 0 H(x-1)dx
```

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Change of variables, $y=x-1$. Then we are integrating $H(y)$ from $-1$ to $1$.

Note that between $-1$ and $0$, $H(y)=0$. So, you only have to integrate $H(y)$ from $0$ to $1$. In this interval, $H(y)$ is a constant function, equal to $1$ and hence the integral equals $1$.